# Why does the Megilla assume the listeners are hard of hearing?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Megilla starts,

Narrator:

> And it was in the days of Achasverosh

Audience:

> Who?

Narrator:

> Achasverosh

Why does the Megilla assume that the people listening are hard of hearing?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

The *M'gila* starts with the party of *Achashverosh*. The *midrash* explains that *Achashverosh* threw this party upon realizing (incorrectly) that the prophesied seventy years of exile were concluded and the *bes hamikdash* would no longer be built. He had items from the *bes hamikdash* taken out of storage, the *midrash* continues, and used at the party, to show his invitees there was no longer any *bes hamikdash* to worry about.

We know he invited Jews to the party: this is one reason the *midrash* gives for *Haman*'s edict to destroy them. But obviously he did not invite all Jews. I propose that he invited those who would be most emotionally affected by the signs that there would be no *bes hamikdash*: the ones who would otherwise be building it. Taking his clue from the description of the building of the first *bes hamikdash* ([Ⅰ *M'lachim* 7:14](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%93)), *Achashverosh* invited

> בן אשה אלמנה… ממטה נפתלי ואביו איש צרי חרש
>   the son of a widow from *Naftali* whose father was from *Tzor*. He was deaf.

It was he who said "Who?".

Answer (score 2):

Just assumes that they are already after a few lechaims.

Answer (score 2):

By the Chasidim it is not who it is he, so he is deaf, Achasverosh is deaf.